# Splitting data-attribute before second hyphen

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Hi guys I am trying to look at a string which looks like this: `'sl-test-one-two'`.
I want to split this string into looking like this: `'sl-test'`. I am trying to do this by matching a regex to the data-attribute which i am being returned, but I cant seem to get it right.

My code:

```
var breadcrumbBrand = $(".breadcrumb-navigation__link").last().attr("data-category-id");

var test = breadcrumbBrand.match(\A[^-]+-[^-]+);

console.log(test);
```

Comment: you want to split or match ?

Comment: It is JS, not Perl. Use `.match(/^[^-]+-[^-]+/);` and access the `[0]` item in the resulting array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the regex

```
^[^-]+\-[^-]+
```

check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/Mzq9o7/1/)

```js
function matchStr(str){
    console.log(str.match(/^[^-]+\-[^-]+/g));
}

matchStr('sl-test-one-two');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```js
var str='sl-test-one-two';
var res=str.split(/(.*?-.*?)-/g);
console.log(res[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var strng='sl-test-one-two';
var str1=strng.split(/(.*?-.*?)-/g);
console.log(str1[1]);
```